# Unable to find region for hello_world

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-pig

Versions: Hadoop 2.2, Hbase 0.96.1, Pig 0.12

Whenever I run this pig script

> raw_data = LOAD 'sample_data.csv' USING PigStorage( ',' ) AS (
>   listing_id: chararray,    fname: chararray,    lname: chararray );
>
> STORE raw_data INTO 'hbase://hello_world' USING
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage (    'info:fname
>   info:lname');

And the log show me this:

> 2014-01-15 20:12:30,788 [main-SendThread(hadoop-master:2181)] INFO 
>   org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Socket connection established to
>   hadoop-master/50.50.1.15:2181, initiating session 2014-01-15
>   20:12:30,798 [main-SendThread(hadoop-master:2181)] INFO 
>   org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Session establishment complete on
>   server hadoop-master/50.50.1.15:2181, sessionid = 0x14397878303000b,
>   negotiated timeout = 90000

which seems OK, but after 10min, this error shows me:

> 2014-01-15 20:23:10,247 [main] ERROR
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableOutputFormat -
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.NoServerForRegionException: Unable to
>   find region for hello_world,,99999999999999 after 10 tries. 2014-01-15
>   20:23:10,250 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR
>   2999: Unexpected internal error.
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.NoServerForRegionException: Unable to
>   find region for hello_world,,99999999999999 after 10 tries.

To check if everything is OK, I typed this command to check: `hbase hbck` and give me this:

```
Summary:
  hbase:meta is okay.
    Number of regions: 1
    Deployed on:  hadoop-master,60020,1389816680166
  hello_world is okay.
    Number of regions: 1
    Deployed on:  ubuntu-5e1cfa86-44db-4cab-a902-2aa87485669f,60020,1389816681502
  hbase:namespace is okay.
    Number of regions: 1
    Deployed on:  hadoop-master,60020,1389816680166
0 inconsistencies detected.
Status: OK
```

In `jps`, my cluster give me the `HRegionServer` and `HQuorumPeer` in master, `Hmaster` on my master

My jps master:

```
29660 ResourceManager
29264 NameNode
32372 HRegionServer
32064 HQuorumPeer
32159 HMaster
586 Jps
29513 SecondaryNameNode
31728 JobHistoryServer
```

My jps slave:

```
29817 Jps
29071 HRegionServer
26844 NodeManager
26665 DataNode
28731 JobHistoryServer
```

Only error that give is the `hbase hbck` because It runs and close before the zookeeper continue I think. And this error

```
2014-01-16 13:27:44,149 INFO  [master:hadoop-master:60000] master.MasterFileSystem: Log folder hdfs://hadoop-master:8020/hbase/WALs/ubuntu-5e1cfa86-44db-4cab-a902-2aa87485669f,60020,1389878859822 belongs to an existing region server
2014-01-16 13:27:44,234 INFO  [master:hadoop-master:60000] catalog.CatalogTracker: Failed verification of hbase:meta,,1 at address=ubuntu-5e1cfa86-44db-4cab-a902-2aa87485669f,60020,1389876721606, exception=org.apache.hadoop.hbase.NotServingRegionException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.NotServingRegionException: Region hbase:meta,,1 is not online
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.getRegionByEncodedName(HRegionServer.java:2585)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.getRegion(HRegionServer.java:3952)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.getRegionInfo(HRegionServer.java:3369)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.AdminProtos$AdminService$2.callBlockingMethod(AdminProtos.java:19789)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:2175)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer$Handler.run(RpcServer.java:1879)
```

.There's anything I'm missing?

Updating: possible error are jar files are incorrect, hbase client are trying to connecting to master, which i fixed and still with errors.

Comment: The last error, i got it fixed, but still figuring it out how to fix it

Comment: did you can add records to hello_world table via hbase shell in command line?

Comment: I've tested, and yes. I can add records manually by terminal.

Comment: Do all pig inserts fail (if you play around with different inputs)? Can you try something like `text,text,text` rather than `text,empty,number`?